# Pointers behaviour in different datatype

Tags: c, pointers, struct

```
struct check{
unsigned short a;
unsigned short b;
};

static unsigned char v[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
struct check *p = (struct check *)v;

printf("%d",p->a);
printf("\t%d",p->b);
```

The answer is `513` and `1027`. I am not able to get why it is happening. Can anybody help me on understanding the concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated**

Here's what appears to be happening... The array of characters is laid out in memory as follows:

```
v+0: 0x01
v+1: 0x02
v+2: 0x03
v+3: 0x04
v+4: 0x05
```

When you cast `v` to be of type `struct check *` and dereference it, this region of memory is being reinterpreted as follows:

```
p->a: 0x0201 (v+1, v+0)
p->b: 0x0403 (v+3, v+2)
```

`0x0201` in hexadecimal is equal to 513, and `0x0403` is equal to 1027.

**Additional thoughts...**

It's important to note that you can't guarantee anything about the behavior of your code. For starters, dereferencing `p` is a strict aliasing violation. See [What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) for an explanation of the strict aliasing rule as well as a list of other factors that affect this type of code.

Comment: Realistically you can't guarantee anything about the behavior of this code as dereferencing p constitutes a strict aliasing violation.

Comment: @tab Thanks... I've updated my answer to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 5):

It's not a good idea to cast pointers like this.

Probably, `unsigned short` is 2 bytes on your machine, and after the cast, `p->a` gets the value `0x0201`, which is decimal `513`, and `p->b` gets the value of `0x0403`, which is decimal `1027`.

Note that the result will be different on a machine with different endianess. For example, on my machine, the output is `258` (`0x0102`) and `772` (`0x0304`).

Also note that you should use format specifier `%u` to print values of `unsigned` type:

```
printf("%u\t%u\n", p->a, p->b);
```

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Nice, I'll add a note on that.